# Query error: Failed to recognize predicate 'group'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in subquery source

Tags: sql, hive

I tried the below query in hive. I get the error "Failed to recognize predicate 'group'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in subquery source".

From my understanding, I am not sure on what does that error mean in the below query. Any suggestions would be great !!

```
select val1, val2, count(distinct(val3)) from (
    select val1, val2, val3
    from tab1
    where (val1 in ('A', 'B') 
    or val2 in ('C', 'D')))
group by val1, val2
```

Comment: You need a where clause right?

Comment: Replace the `and` with a `where` on the subquery.

Comment: @JacobH and WEI_DBA, sorry it was a typo. Even with a where clause i get the error.

Comment: Please update your post to what is not working and can you post the actual error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to alias your sub-query:

```
select val1, val2, count(distinct(val3)) from (
    select val1, val2, val3
    from tab1
    where (val1 in ('A', 'B') 
    or val2 in ('C', 'D'))) as t
group by val1, val2
```

Comment: Overlook the obvious... Good catch! +1